# No puedo enviar videos a través de jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, php7

Estoy creando un nuevo módulo en mi web en el que ingresen una pequeña información para la divulgación. Para esto, creé un sencillo formulario:

```
function formulario(){

    ?>

    <form id="formularioDivulgacion" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="hidden" name="idProyectoDivulgacion" id="idProyectoDivulgacion" value="<?php echo $this->id; ?>">

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="nombreResultado">Nombre resultado de investigación:</label>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreResultado" name="nombreResultado" placeholder="Nombre del resultado de investigación para su divulgación..." value="<?php echo $this->modelo->consultarInformacion($this->id, 'nombre_tecnologia'); ?>" readonly>

            <small id="ayudaNombreResultado" class="form-text text-muted">El nombre del resultado de investigación es lo que se mostrará al público.</small>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="resumenResultado">Sinópsis del resultado de investigación:</label>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="resumenResultado" name="resumenResultado" placeholder="Sinópsis del resultado de investigación..." value="<?php echo $this->modelo->consultarInformacion($this->id, 'resumen_proyecto'); ?>">

            <small id="ayudaSinopsisResultado" class="form-text text-muted">Esta sinópsis será lo que las personas observen, sin necesidad de entrar al vídeo.</small>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="videoResultado">Subir vídeo explicativo.</label>

            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="videoResultado" name="videoResultado">

            <small id="ayudaSinopsisResultado" class="form-text text-muted">Este vídeo es la forma en la que mejor se dará a conocer el porqué, el cómo y el para qué del resultado de investigación.</small>

        </div>

        <?php

        if ($this->modelo->consultarInformacion($this->id, 'video_proyecto') != NULL && $this->modelo->consultarInformacion($this->id, 'video_proyecto') != "") {

            ?>

            <video id="preVideoDivulgacion" src="../videos/divulgacion/<?php $this->modelo->consultarInformacion($this->id, 'video_proyecto'); ?>" style="min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" controls></video>

            <?php

        }else{

            ?>

            <video id="preVideoDivulgacion" style="display: none; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" controls></video>

            <?php

        }

        ?>

    </form>

    <br><br>

    <?php

}
```

La información del resumen y el video, al detectar cambios, envía los datos de este formulario. Por el momento, lo he intentado sólo cuando cambie el video:

```
$(document).on("change", "#videoResultado", function(e){

    var TmpPath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

    $("#preVideoDivulgacion").attr('src', TmpPath);

    $("#preVideoDivulgacion").show(500);

    var form = $('#formularioDivulgacion')[0];

    var formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({

        method: 'POST',
        url: '../recepcion/recepcionDivulgacion.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){

            alert(data);

        }

    });

});
```

El problema viene con el alert, pues al recibirlo de en PHP, no me muestra absolutamente nada. Debería mostrarme el nombre y el nombre temporal:

```
if (isset($_POST['idProyectoDivulgacion']) && isset($_POST['nombreResultado']) && isset($_POST['resumenResultado'])) {

    $c = new controladorDivulgacion();

    echo $_FILES['videoResultado']['name'] . " - " . $_FILES['videoResultado']['tmp_name'];

    //echo $c->guardarVideo($_FILES['videoResultado']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['videoResultado']['name']);

}
```

Lastimosamente, no me muestra nada. No sé qué error tengo, pues los demás datos sí son enviados.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás sea por el tipo de dato con el que lo recibes, no estoy seguro.
Pero podrías probar en el "success" poniendo un "dataType" quedando algo así:

```
$.ajax({

        method: 'POST',
        url: '../recepcion/recepcionDivulgacion.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(dataType){

            alert(dataType);

        }

    });
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, o al menos te dé una pista.